# Updating query using where and matching with Cakephp 3.X - is it possible?

Tags: cakephp, join, sql-update, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

Trying to update some rows based on related data, using matching.
But only the "where" clause is working. The "matching" is ignored!

Am I, doing something wrong?

```
$tbTU = TableRegistry::get('TaskUsers');
$query = $tbTU->query()
    ->where([
        'TaskUsers.service_order_id' => $so_id,
        'TaskUsers.status IN' => [0, 4, 7, 9],
    ]) 
    ->contain(['Tasks'])
    ->matching('Tasks', function($q) {
        return $q->where([
            'Tasks.task_type IN' => [1, 4, 5]
        ]); 
    });

return $query
    ->update()
    ->set([
        'status' => 3,
        'user_id' => NULL,
        'modified' => Time::now()
    ])
    ->execute();
```

Thanks!!

Comment: I think it's not possible. Anyway what are the relationships between your models? Seems you don't need a matching statement if a `TaskUser` belongsTo `Task`

Comment: Yes, TaskUsers belongs to Tasks. How could I update a TaskUser with status 4 or 7, wich belongs to a Task with a task_type  1 or 5, without using matching, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the answer to your question is no, according to [**this**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/8777) issue

As @ndm says in the comments you can use a subquery depending on your DBMS

I would do something like this:

```
$subquery = $this->TaskUsers->Tasks->find()
    ->select(['id'])
    ->where(['Tasks.task_type IN' => [1, 4, 5]]);

$tbTU->query()
    ->where([
        'TaskUsers.service_order_id' => $so_id,
        'TaskUsers.status IN' => [0, 4, 7, 9],
        'TaskUsers.task_id IN' => $subquery
    ])
});
```

Comment: Joins aren't supported, hence you also cannot use containments. For update queries with joins one has to write the query completely manually. Alternatively using subqueries might be possible, which however has certain limitations depending on the DBMS too.

Comment: @ndm yes, of course you're totally right. I'll delete or edit my answer